# How can i get Discord Users Activity of my discord server?

Tags: discord

I want to make a discord bot using javascript. Which can get Discord User activity.
can anyone help to get this?

Comment: Start with looking through the API to see if it has what fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Api . To do this, go to the  [Discord developers](https://discord.com/developers)  website and register to get api panel it. After confirmation, you can use the developer Guide in discord developer to do the rest of the steps.

Comment: If its answered, please vote for my answer